# Wordpress: CSS file not working?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Okay. I've been trying to link the css stylesheets to my webpages. I've been scratching my head trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

functions.php

```
<?php 

function roofers_wp_resources() { 
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());   
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'roofers_wp_resources');

?>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>R.J Roofers</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <?php wp_head(); ?> 

    </head>
<body>
```

front-page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="main-container">
    <header class="main-header">
        <!--        <h1 class="logo-name"><li><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></li></h1>
         -->        <h1 class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></h1>

                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </nav>
            </header>
        <div class="quote-box-1">

            <div class="quote-box">
                <p class="quote-box-title">HOME ROOFING BRISBANE NO.1 FOR ROOF RESTORATIONS AND ROOF REPLACE</p>
                <button class="quote-btn-1">BOOK A FREE QUOTE</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
More Code..
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style( 'core', 'style.css', false );` the second parameter should contain the name of the file you are en queueing. So more like `wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/normalize.css');`

Answer (score 1):

`get_stylesheet_uri()` gives full url to your style.css file, so in your case it's good only if you want to enqueue the style.css file.
For the second file, you need to pass a full url including the name of the file.
Assuming your normalize file called normalize.css:

```
function roofers_wp_resources(){
    wp_enqueue_style('my-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'roofers_wp_resources');
```

Notice that if you working on a child theme, you need to change `get_template_directory_uri()` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Okay. but the issue remains: i cannot even get the style.css working!

Comment: The file is not loading in the page? Check for any errors in the console (Right click in the page->Inspect Element->go to "console" tab)